# Leaflet unit-testing - layer removal (jest)

Tags: leaflet, react

I want to test if FeatureLayer is removed from the map instance, but somehow
instead of `expect(removeCallCount).toBe(1)` I have 0. What can be the problem?

```
  test("FeatureLayer removes itself from map instance when no longer in map", async () => {
      const scope = createMapScope();
      const capture = jest.fn();
      mockAddLayer.mockReset();
      expect(mockAddLayer.mock.calls.length).toBe(0);
      const { rerender } = render(<MapInstanceScope scope={scope}>
        <Map scope={scope}>
          <FeatureLayer>
            <FeatureLayerContext.Consumer>
              {capture}
            </FeatureLayerContext.Consumer>
          </FeatureLayer>
        </Map>
      </MapInstanceScope>);
      const { featureLayer } = capture.mock.calls[capture.mock.calls.length - 1][0] as { featureLayer: L.FeatureGroup };
      let removeCallCount = 0;
      jest.spyOn(featureLayer, "remove").mockImplementation(function(){removeCallCount = removeCallCount + 1; return Leaflet.L.featureGroup(); });
      rerender(<MapInstanceScope scope={scope}>
        <Map scope={scope} />
      </MapInstanceScope>);
      expect(removeCallCount).toBe(1);
    });
```

Instead of `jest.spyOn(featureLayer, "remove")` I also tried such events as removeLayer, removeOn, but none of these worked.

This is a part of the code that is responsible for layer's removal (just in case):

```
export const useMapLayerManager = (layer?: L.Layer, layerProps?: MapLayersContextLayerPropsShape) => {
  const { addLayer, removeLayer } = useContext(MapLayersContext);
  const memoizedLayerProps = useMemo(() => ({
    label: layerProps?.label
  }), [
    layerProps?.label
  ])
  useEffect(() => {
    if(layer){
      addLayer(layer, layerProps);
      return () => {
        removeLayer(layer);
      }
    }
  }, [layer, memoizedLayerProps]); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}
```